# How to Select the most recent items by dates from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables Projects and Plans, and I need get recent projects from the last plan by create date:

```
Projects:
ProjectId, PlanId, StartDate, EndDate 
(guid)     (guid)  (datetime) (datetime)
-------------------------------------
00001,     00001,  1/1/2015   31/1/2015   
00001,     00002,  3/2/2015   15/2/2015   
00002,     00001,  1/2/2015   20/2/2015   
00002,     00002,  1/2/2015   21/2/2015   
00003,     00001,  1/3/2015   10/3/2015   

Plans:
PlanId, CreateDate
(guid)  (datetime)
--------------------
00001,   1/1/2015
00002,   5/2/2015
```

I wrote query that take single project from the last plan, but i can't write query to get many projects by single query.

Here my query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 pr.ProjectId,
        pl.CreateDate,
        pr.StartDate,
        pr.EndDate
FROM   Projects pr
        INNER JOIN Plans pl
            ON  pr.PlanId = pl.PlanId
WHERE ProjectId = '000002'
ORDER BY pl.CreateDate DESC
```

Desired result is (all projects from the last plans):

```
ProjectId, PlanId, StartDate, EndDate
--------------------------------------
00001,     00002,  3/2/2015,  15/2/2015
00002,     00002,  1/2/2015,  21/2/2015
00003,     00001,  1/3/2015,  10/3/2015
```

**UPDATE:**
Gordon Linoff gave the good answer, but it wasn't solved my question, because both his queries don't take '00003' project (its last plan is '00001').

I wrote my query with '[OVER Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189461.aspx)' (Stanislovas Kalašnikovas note about it).

So I post full answer that solves my question for future googlers:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
        result.ProjectId, 
        result.CreateDate, 
        result.StartDate, 
        result.EndDate, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM ( 
            SELECT  pr.ProjectId AS ProjectId,
                    pl.CreateDate AS CreateDate,
                    pr.StartDate AS StartDate,
                    pr.EndDate AS EndDate
            FROM   Projects pr
            INNER JOIN Plans pl ON  pr.PlanId = pl.PlanId
            --WHERE ProjectId IN ('000001', '000003') --Filter
         ) AS result
) AS result
WHERE result.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Cab you please show what is the expected result from the the example data that you provided?

Comment: @Nightmaresux question was changed, I've added desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is example of `ROW_NUMBER` with 1 table, easy you can use It in your case.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
Id NVARCHAR(100),
Data DATE
)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('1', '2015-01-04'), ('1', '2015-01-07'), ('2', '2015-01-05'), ('2', '2015-01-08')

SELECT Id, Data
FROM (
    SELECT Id, Data, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Data DESC) rn
    FROM #Test
    )x
WHERE rn > 1


DROP TABLE #Test
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to get the most recent plan.  Then just join this to projects:

```
SELECT pr.ProjectId, pl.CreateDate, pr.StartDate, pr.EndDate
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 pl.*
      FROM plans pl
      ORDER BY pl.CreateDate DESC
     ) pl JOIN
     Projects pr
     ON pr.PlanId = pl.PlanId;
WHERE ProjectId = '000002'
```

An alternative method is to just use `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES pr.ProjectId, pl.CreateDate, pr.StartDate, pr.EndDate
FROM plans pl
     Projects pr
     ON pr.PlanId = pl.PlanId;
WHERE ProjectId = '000002'
ORDER BY pl.CreateDate DESC
```

Comment: He wants results for all projects, not just for `ProjectID='000002'`. Upvoted though, for using `TOP WITH TIES` ...  *[SQLPolice **never** downvotes]*

Comment: TOP 1 WITH TIES  - I will know about this feature, thank you so much!

Comment: Both queries don't take '00003' project, because his last plan is '00001'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [datediff()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) e.g if you want to take the entries of last 10 days use:

```
SELECT  pr.ProjectId,
        pl.CreateDate,
        pr.StartDate,
        pr.EndDate
FROM   Projects pr
        INNER JOIN Plans pl
            ON  pr.PlanId = pl.PlanId
WHERE datediff(day,pl.CreateDate,getdate())<10
```